How to code a dynamic line?
I'm plotting several points and connecting them with a polyline, the objective is to implement a feature where, if any of the plotted vertices are moved within the scene, the polyline dynamically adjusts its position accordingly to maintain connectivity. I'm using the following code for this task:
# function to draw the line in 3D space 
# it creates a shader object from the built-in shader '3D_UNIFORM_COLOR'
# and a batch object for the shader of 'LINES' type between the positions of the start and end points
# it binds the shader object and sets the color and width
def draw_line_3d(color, start, end):
    shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin('3D_UNIFORM_COLOR')
    batch = batch_for_shader(shader, 'LINES', {"pos": [start, end]})
    shader.bind()
    shader.uniform_float("color", color)
    bgl.glLineWidth(bpy.context.scene.line_width) 
    batch.draw(shader)

# it iterates over the points list and draws a line between each pair of points
# it sets the line width and color
# GL_BLEND: Enables blending of colors for smooth color transitions and transparency effects.
# GL_LINE_SMOOTH: Enables anti-aliasing for smoother rendering of lines.
# GL_DEPTH_TEST: Enables depth testing for correct rendering order based on object distance from the viewer. 
# the draw handler stays enabled until the operator is running
def draw_callback_3d(operator, context):
    bgl.glEnable(bgl.GL_BLEND) 
    bgl.glEnable(bgl.GL_LINE_SMOOTH)
    bgl.glEnable(bgl.GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    
    color = bpy.context.scene.line_color 
    
    for i in range(len(points_list) - 1):
        start = points_list[i]
        end = points_list[i + 1]
        draw_line_3d(color, start, end)
    
    bgl.glLineWidth(bpy.context.scene.line_width) 
    bgl.glDisable(bgl.GL_BLEND)
    bgl.glDisable(bgl.GL_LINE_SMOOTH)
    bgl.glEnable(bgl.GL_DEPTH_TEST)

# operator to draw the line in 3D space
# it adds the draw_callback_3d function to the draw handler 
# and sets the modal handler for the operator
class LineDrawOperator(Operator):
    bl_idname = "view3d.line_draw_operator"
    bl_label = "Line Draw Operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        if context.area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            args = (self, context)
            self._handle_3d = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw_callback_3d, args, 'WINDOW', 'POST_VIEW')
            context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
            

# operator to plot a point in 3D space
# it sets the cursor location to the coordinates of the point
# adds a vertex at the cursor location
# appends the coordinates of the point to the points list
# prints the points list
class PointPlotterOperator(Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.point_plotter"
    bl_label = "Plot Point"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    x_coordinate: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="X Coordinate", default=0.0)
    y_coordinate: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Y Coordinate", default=0.0)
    z_coordinate: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Z Coordinate", default=0.0)

    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        bpy.context.scene.cursor.location = (self.x_coordinate, self.y_coordinate, self.z_coordinate)
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_vert_add()
        points_list.append((self.x_coordinate, self.y_coordinate, self.z_coordinate))
        print(points_list)
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)

I've managed to plot the points and draw the initial polyline, but I'm struggling to figure out how to make the polyline update its position in real-time as the vertices are dragged. How can I achieve this dynamic behavior in my code?
